# How can I include a YAML file inside another?

Tags: yaml, transclusion

So I have two YAML files, "A" and "B" and I want the contents of A to be inserted inside B, either spliced into the existing data structure, like an array, or as a child of an element, like the value for a certain hash key.

Is this possible at all? How? If not, any pointers to a normative reference?

Comment: I've recently bumped into [HiYaPyCo](https://github.com/zerwes/hiyapyco) for Python that does exactly this. You can merge different YAML files together. Is is a very nice Python module that worth knowing.

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620674/use-placeholders-in-yaml

Answer (score 504, accepted):

No, standard YAML does not include any kind of "import" or "include" statement.

Comment: You could create a !include <filename> handler.

Comment: @clarkevans sure, but that construct would be "outside" the YAML language.

Comment: If you're using Rails, you can insert <%= 'fdsa fdsa' %> ERB syntax and it will work

Comment: I think this answer should be rephrased as "No, standard YAML doesn't include this function. Nevertheless many implementations provides some extension to do so."

Comment: imports:
    #   Common default parameters and country selection
    - { resource: parameters.yml

Comment: And the lack of that support is a good thing. It has been a great source of error and security flaw for other configuration file types.

Answer (score 169):

Your question does not ask for a Python solution, but here is one using [PyYAML](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml).

PyYAML allows you to attach custom constructors (such as `!include`) to the YAML loader. I've included a root directory that can be set so that this solution supports relative and absolute file references.

## Class-Based Solution

Here is a class-based solution, that avoids the global root variable of my original response.

See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/joshbode/569627ced3076931b02f) for a similar, more robust Python 3 solution that uses a metaclass to register the custom constructor.

```python
import yaml
import os

class Loader(yaml.SafeLoader):

    def __init__(self, stream):

        self._root = os.path.split(stream.name)[0]

        super(Loader, self).__init__(stream)

    def include(self, node):

        filename = os.path.join(self._root, self.construct_scalar(node))

        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            return yaml.load(f, Loader)

Loader.add_constructor('!include', Loader.include)
```

An example:

**`foo.yaml`**

```
a: 1
b:
    - 1.43
    - 543.55
c: !include bar.yaml
```

**`bar.yaml`**

```
- 3.6
- [1, 2, 3]
```

Now the files can be loaded using:

```python
>>> with open('foo.yaml', 'r') as f:
>>>    data = yaml.load(f, Loader)
>>> data
{'a': 1, 'b': [1.43, 543.55], 'c': [3.6, [1, 2, 3]]}
```

Comment: This is an intresting feature, thanx. But what is the purpose of all these manipulations with root/old_root? I suppose the code of `include` function can simplified:                                   
`
    def include(loader, node):
        """Include another YAML file."""
        filename = loader.construct_scalar(node)
        data = yaml.load(open(filename))
`

Comment: The root global is there so that relative includes work at any depth, e.g. when included files sitting in a different directory include a file relative to that directory. Absolute includes should work, too. There's probably a cleaner way to do this without a global variable, perhaps using a custom yaml.Loader class.

Comment: Is it also possible to have something like this:
foo.yaml: 
`a: bla`

bar.yaml:
`
!include foo.yaml
b: blubb`

So that the result would be:
`{'a': bla, 'b': blubb}

Comment: @martin I think it would probably be difficult to achieve without messing with the Parser and/or Reader class to effectively inject the included file into the token stream. It definitely won't work the way I have done it above.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Also, a security nitpick, you should use yaml.safeload instead of yaml.load, to avoid specially crafted yaml from owning your service.

Comment: @danielpops good point - however, I couldn't see a way to get `yaml.safe_load` to use a custom loader

Comment: @JoshBode this should work for you: https://gist.github.com/danielpops/5a0726f2fb6288da749c4cd604276be8

Comment: Thanks @danielpops - updated above, and in referenced gist

Comment: Sorry for bother you guys, but you can awnser me if is possible to do import just from a specific data from the second file? Something like:
foo.yaml
c: !include {list [1, 2, 3] from bar.yaml}

Comment: I create a new question (based in that one) about my comment above, if someone want discust in a proper page

Comment: not working for me. my yaml file has "#include shared.yaml". I've tried the above solution but still getting "found undefined alias" error. I change !include -> #include, still same issue. didn't understand where class Loader being used?

Comment: @imankalyan - please link to a gist or similar with a minimal working example that demonstrates your issue. note: `#include` is just a comment in YAML - you will definitely need to use the form `!include`

Answer (score 25):

For Python users, you can try [pyyaml-include](https://github.com/tanbro/pyyaml-include).

### Install

```sh
pip install pyyaml-include
```

### Usage

```py
import yaml
from yamlinclude import YamlIncludeConstructor

YamlIncludeConstructor.add_to_loader_class(loader_class=yaml.FullLoader, base_dir='/your/conf/dir')

with open('0.yaml') as f:
    data = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

print(data)
```

Consider we have such [YAML](http://yaml.org/) files:

```
├── 0.yaml
└── include.d
    ├── 1.yaml
    └── 2.yaml
```

- `1.yaml` 's content:

```
name: "1"
```

- `2.yaml` 's content:

```
name: "2"
```

#### Include files by name

- On top level:

  If `0.yaml` was:

```
!include include.d/1.yaml
```

We'll get:

```
{"name": "1"}
```

- In mapping:

  If `0.yaml` was:

```
file1: !include include.d/1.yaml
file2: !include include.d/2.yaml
```

We'll get:

```
  file1:
    name: "1"
  file2:
    name: "2"
```

- In sequence:

  If `0.yaml` was:

```
files:
  - !include include.d/1.yaml
  - !include include.d/2.yaml
```

We'll get:

```
files:
  - name: "1"
  - name: "2"
```

> ℹ **Note**:
>
> File name can be either absolute (like `/usr/conf/1.5/Make.yml`) or relative (like `../../cfg/img.yml`).

#### Include files by wildcards

File name can contain shell-style wildcards. Data loaded from the file(s) found by wildcards will be set in a sequence.

If `0.yaml` was:

```
files: !include include.d/*.yaml
```

We'll get:

```
files:
  - name: "1"
  - name: "2"
```

> ℹ **Note**:
>
> - For `Python>=3.5`, if `recursive` argument of `!include` [YAML](http://yaml.org/) tag is `true`, the pattern `“**”` will match any files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
> - Using the `“**”` pattern in large directory trees may consume an inordinate amount of time because of recursive search.

In order to enable `recursive` argument, we shall write the `!include` tag in `Mapping` or `Sequence` mode:

- Arguments in `Sequence` mode:

```
!include [tests/data/include.d/**/*.yaml, true]
```

- Arguments in `Mapping` mode:

```
!include {pathname: tests/data/include.d/**/*.yaml, recursive: true}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. It pertains to a Python solution, not one using the standardized YAML format.

Comment: @oligofren Custom tag handlers is a feature of YAML, allowing parsers to extend YAML to specify types and implement custom behaviors like these. It would be a long stretch for YAML specification itself to go as far as to prescribe how file inclusion should work with all the disparate OS path specs, filesystems, etc.

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff Thank you for bring that to my attention. Could you point me to such a place in the RFC? It has no mention of the word "custom". Ref https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html

Comment: @oligofren You’re welcome. Look for “application-specific” [tags](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#tag/handle/).

Comment: great lib, but it will not support anchors

Answer (score 24):

The YML standard **does not** specify a way to do this. And this problem does not limit itself to YML. JSON has the same limitations.

Many applications which use YML or JSON based configurations run into this problem eventually. And when that happens, **they make up their own convention**.

e.g. for swagger API definitions:

```
$ref: 'file.yml'
```

e.g. for docker compose configurations:

```
services:
  app:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose.base.yml
```

Alternatively, if you want to split up the content of a yml file in multiple files, like a tree of content, you can define your own folder-structure convention and use an (existing) merge script.

Comment: This should be higher up. Most of the time if you need to import a YAML into another it's because of some config file from a specific framework, and it's always worth looking into whether the framework itself offers a way to do it without reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 23):

Includes are not directly supported in YAML as far as I know, you will have to provide a mechanism yourself however, this is generally easy to do.

I have used YAML as a configuration language in my python apps, and in this case often define a convention like this:

```
>>> main.yml <<<
includes: [ wibble.yml, wobble.yml]
```

Then in my (python) code I do:

```
import yaml
cfg = yaml.load(open("main.yml"))
for inc in cfg.get("includes", []):
   cfg.update(yaml.load(open(inc)))
```

The only down side is that variables in the includes will always override the variables in main, and there is no way to change that precedence by changing where the "includes: statement appears in the main.yml file.

On a slightly different point, YAML doesn't support includes as its not really designed as as exclusively   as a file based mark up. What would an include mean if you got it in a response to an AJAX request?

Comment: this only works when the yaml file doesn't contain nested configuration.

Answer (score 10):

Expanding on @Josh_Bode's answer, here's my own PyYAML solution, which has the advantage of being a self-contained subclass of `yaml.Loader`. It doesn't depend on any module-level globals, or on modifying the global state of the `yaml` module.

```py
import yaml, os

class IncludeLoader(yaml.Loader):                                                 
    """                                                                           
    yaml.Loader subclass handles "!include path/to/foo.yml" directives in config  
    files.  When constructed with a file object, the root path for includes       
    defaults to the directory containing the file, otherwise to the current       
    working directory. In either case, the root path can be overridden by the     
    `root` keyword argument.                                                      

    When an included file F contain its own !include directive, the path is       
    relative to F's location.                                                     

    Example:                                                                      
        YAML file /home/frodo/one-ring.yml:                                       
            ---                                                                   
            Name: The One Ring                                                    
            Specials:                                                             
                - resize-to-wearer                                                
            Effects: 
                - !include path/to/invisibility.yml                            

        YAML file /home/frodo/path/to/invisibility.yml:                           
            ---                                                                   
            Name: invisibility                                                    
            Message: Suddenly you disappear!                                      

        Loading:                                                                  
            data = IncludeLoader(open('/home/frodo/one-ring.yml', 'r')).get_data()

        Result:                                                                   
            {'Effects': [{'Message': 'Suddenly you disappear!', 'Name':            
                'invisibility'}], 'Name': 'The One Ring', 'Specials':              
                ['resize-to-wearer']}                                             
    """                                                                           
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):                                          
        super(IncludeLoader, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)                      
        self.add_constructor('!include', self._include)                           
        if 'root' in kwargs:                                                      
            self.root = kwargs['root']                                            
        elif isinstance(self.stream, file):                                       
            self.root = os.path.dirname(self.stream.name)                         
        else:                                                                     
            self.root = os.path.curdir                                            

    def _include(self, loader, node):                                    
        oldRoot = self.root                                              
        filename = os.path.join(self.root, loader.construct_scalar(node))
        self.root = os.path.dirname(filename)                           
        data = yaml.load(open(filename, 'r'))                            
        self.root = oldRoot                                              
        return data
```

Comment: Finally got around to adding the class-based approach to my answer, but you beat me to the punch :) Note: If you use `yaml.load(f, IncludeLoader)` within `_include` you can avoid having to replace the root. Also, unless you do this, the solution will not work more than one level deep as the included data uses the regular `yaml.Loader` class.

Comment: I had to remove the keyword `root` of `kwargs` after setting `self.root` to get it working with strings. I moved the if-else block above the `super` call. Maybe someone else can confirm my finding or show me how to use the class with strings and the `root` parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work with references such as

```
included: &INCLUDED
    !include inner.yaml

merge:
    <<: *INCLUDED
```

Answer (score 7):

With [Yglu](https://yglu.io), you can import other files like this:

**A.yaml**

```
foo: !? $import('B.yaml')
```

**B.yaml**

```
bar: Hello
```

```
$ yglu A.yaml
foo:
  bar: Hello
```

As `$import` is a function, you can also pass an expression as argument:

```
  dep: !- b
  foo: !? $import($_.dep.toUpper() + '.yaml')
```

This would give the same output as above.

Disclaimer: I am the author of Yglu.

Comment: Nice, just a CLI. The only solution on this thread which doesn't require to create a Python program, if you don't want to deal (primarily) with Python.

Comment: Tried Yglu for a project that deals with many languages, but I ended up getting some `charmap: can't decode byte...`-type errors. Leaving a comment here to save other people some time.

Answer (score 3):

Standard YAML 1.2 doesn't include natively this feature. Nevertheless many implementations provides some extension to do so.

I present a way of achieving it with Java and `snakeyaml:1.24` (Java library to parse/emit YAML files) that allows creating a custom YAML tag to achieve the following goal (you will see I'm using it to load test suites defined in several YAML files and that I made it work as a list of includes for a target `test:` node):

```
# ... yaml prev stuff

tests: !include
  - '1.hello-test-suite.yaml'
  - '3.foo-test-suite.yaml'
  - '2.bar-test-suite.yaml'

# ... more yaml document
```

Here is the one-class Java that allows processing the `!include` tag. Files are loaded from classpath (Maven resources directory):

```java
/**
 * Custom YAML loader. It adds support to the custom !include tag which allows splitting a YAML file across several
 * files for a better organization of YAML tests.
 */
@Slf4j   // <-- This is a Lombok annotation to auto-generate logger
public class MyYamlLoader {

    private static final Constructor CUSTOM_CONSTRUCTOR = new MyYamlConstructor();

    private MyYamlLoader() {
    }

    /**
     * Parse the only YAML document in a stream and produce the Java Map. It provides support for the custom !include
     * YAML tag to split YAML contents across several files.
     */
    public static Map<String, Object> load(InputStream inputStream) {
        return new Yaml(CUSTOM_CONSTRUCTOR)
                .load(inputStream);
    }


    /**
     * Custom SnakeYAML constructor that registers custom tags.
     */
    private static class MyYamlConstructor extends Constructor {

        private static final String TAG_INCLUDE = "!include";

        MyYamlConstructor() {
            // Register custom tags
            yamlConstructors.put(new Tag(TAG_INCLUDE), new IncludeConstruct());
        }

        /**
         * The actual include tag construct.
         */
        private static class IncludeConstruct implements Construct {

            @Override
            public Object construct(Node node) {
                List<Node> inclusions = castToSequenceNode(node);
                return parseInclusions(inclusions);
            }

            @Override
            public void construct2ndStep(Node node, Object object) {
                // do nothing
            }

            private List<Node> castToSequenceNode(Node node) {
                try {
                    return ((SequenceNode) node).getValue();

                } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("The !import value must be a sequence node, but " +
                            "'%s' found.", node));
                }
            }

            private Object parseInclusions(List<Node> inclusions) {

                List<InputStream> inputStreams = inputStreams(inclusions);

                try (final SequenceInputStream sequencedInputStream =
                             new SequenceInputStream(Collections.enumeration(inputStreams))) {

                    return new Yaml(CUSTOM_CONSTRUCTOR)
                            .load(sequencedInputStream);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error("Error closing the stream.", e);
                    return null;
                }
            }

            private List<InputStream> inputStreams(List<Node> scalarNodes) {
                return scalarNodes.stream()
                        .map(this::inputStream)
                        .collect(toList());
            }

            private InputStream inputStream(Node scalarNode) {
                String filePath = castToScalarNode(scalarNode).getValue();
                final InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath);
                Assert.notNull(is, String.format("Resource file %s not found.", filePath));
                return is;
            }

            private ScalarNode castToScalarNode(Node scalarNode) {
                try {
                    return ((ScalarNode) scalarNode);

                } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("The value must be a scalar node, but '%s' found" +
                            ".", scalarNode));
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Nice for simple cases; references are not carried over from included files, unfortunately.

Comment: Hi there! What do you mean by "references"? Do you mean transitive `!include`s? If this is what you mean, I didn't think about that. But I guess that support could be added to the solution by recursively calling the `load()` until no `!include`s are left. Does it make sense?

Comment: Seems I didn't use the correct terminology: anchors and aliases (https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-aliases) are what doesn't work. Looking at the snakeyaml v1 source, it would be quite hard to add. Mabye v2 (aka snakeyaml engine) is a bit more modular ...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately YAML doesn't provide this in its standard.

But if you are using Ruby, there is a gem providing the functionality you are asking for by extending the ruby YAML library:
https://github.com/entwanderer/yaml_extend

Answer (score 2):

I make some examples for your reference.

```py
import yaml

main_yaml = """
Package:
 - !include _shape_yaml    
 - !include _path_yaml
"""

_shape_yaml = """
# Define
Rectangle: &id_Rectangle
    name: Rectangle
    width: &Rectangle_width 20
    height: &Rectangle_height 10
    area: !product [*Rectangle_width, *Rectangle_height]

Circle: &id_Circle
    name: Circle
    radius: &Circle_radius 5
    area: !product [*Circle_radius, *Circle_radius, pi]

# Setting
Shape:
    property: *id_Rectangle
    color: red
"""

_path_yaml = """
# Define
Root: &BASE /path/src/

Paths: 
    a: &id_path_a !join [*BASE, a]
    b: &id_path_b !join [*BASE, b]

# Setting
Path:
    input_file: *id_path_a
"""


# define custom tag handler
def yaml_import(loader, node):
    other_yaml_file = loader.construct_scalar(node)
    return yaml.load(eval(other_yaml_file), Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)


def yaml_product(loader, node):
    import math
    list_data = loader.construct_sequence(node)
    result = 1
    pi = math.pi
    for val in list_data:
        result *= eval(val) if isinstance(val, str) else val
    return result


def yaml_join(loader, node):
    seq = loader.construct_sequence(node)
    return ''.join([str(i) for i in seq])


def yaml_ref(loader, node):
    ref = loader.construct_sequence(node)
    return ref[0]


def yaml_dict_ref(loader: yaml.loader.SafeLoader, node):
    dict_data, key, const_value = loader.construct_sequence(node)
    return dict_data[key] + str(const_value)


def main():
    # register the tag handler
    yaml.SafeLoader.add_constructor(tag='!include', constructor=yaml_import)
    yaml.SafeLoader.add_constructor(tag='!product', constructor=yaml_product)
    yaml.SafeLoader.add_constructor(tag='!join', constructor=yaml_join)
    yaml.SafeLoader.add_constructor(tag='!ref', constructor=yaml_ref)
    yaml.SafeLoader.add_constructor(tag='!dict_ref', constructor=yaml_dict_ref)

    config = yaml.load(main_yaml, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)

    pk_shape, pk_path = config['Package']
    pk_shape, pk_path = pk_shape['Shape'], pk_path['Path']
    print(f"shape name: {pk_shape['property']['name']}")
    print(f"shape area: {pk_shape['property']['area']}")
    print(f"shape color: {pk_shape['color']}")

    print(f"input file: {pk_path['input_file']}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

output

```
shape name: Rectangle
shape area: 200
shape color: red
input file: /path/src/a
```

## Update 2

and you can combine it, like this

```
# xxx.yaml
CREATE_FONT_PICTURE:
  PROJECTS:
    SUNG: &id_SUNG
      name: SUNG
      work_dir: SUNG
      output_dir: temp
      font_pixel: 24


  DEFINE: &id_define !ref [*id_SUNG]  # you can use config['CREATE_FONT_PICTURE']['DEFINE'][name, work_dir, ... font_pixel]
  AUTO_INIT:
    basename_suffix: !dict_ref [*id_define, name, !product [5, 3, 2]]  # SUNG30

# ↓ This is not correct.
# basename_suffix: !dict_ref [*id_define, name, !product [5, 3, 2]]  # It will build by Deep-level. id_define is Deep-level: 2. So you must put it after 2. otherwise, it can't refer to the correct value.
```

Answer (score 1):

With **Symfony**, its handling of yaml will indirectly allow you to nest yaml files. The trick is to make use of the `parameters` option. eg:

**common.yml**

```
parameters:
    yaml_to_repeat:
        option: "value"
        foo:
            - "bar"
            - "baz"
```

**config.yml**

```
imports:
    - { resource: common.yml }
whatever:
    thing: "%yaml_to_repeat%"
    other_thing: "%yaml_to_repeat%"
```

The result will be the same as:

```
whatever:
    thing:
        option: "value"
        foo:
            - "bar"
            - "baz"
    other_thing:
        option: "value"
        foo:
            - "bar"
            - "baz"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution used by @maxy-B looks great. However, it didn't succeed for me with nested inclusions. For example if config_1.yaml includes config_2.yaml, which includes config_3.yaml there was a problem with the loader. However, if you simply point the new loader class to itself on load, it works! Specifically, if we replace the old _include function with the very slightly modified version:

```
def _include(self, loader, node):                                    
     oldRoot = self.root                                              
     filename = os.path.join(self.root, loader.construct_scalar(node))
     self.root = os.path.dirname(filename)                           
     data = yaml.load(open(filename, 'r'), loader = IncludeLoader)                            
     self.root = oldRoot                                              
     return data
```

Upon reflection I agree with the other comments, that nested loading is not appropriate for yaml in general as the input stream may not be a file,  but it is very useful!

Answer (score 1):

Combining other answers, here is a short solution without overloading `Loader` class and it works with any loader operating on files:

```py
import json
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Any

import yaml


def yaml_include_constructor(loader: yaml.BaseLoader, node: yaml.Node) -> Any:
    """Include file referenced with !include node"""

    # noinspection PyTypeChecker
    fp = Path(loader.name).parent.joinpath(loader.construct_scalar(node)).resolve()
    fe = fp.suffix.lstrip(".")

    with open(fp, 'r') as f:
        if fe in ("yaml", "yml"):
            return yaml.load(f, type(loader))
        elif fe in ("json", "jsn"):
            return json.load(f)
        else:
            return f.read()


def main():
    loader = yaml.SafeLoader  # Works with any loader
    loader.add_constructor("!include", yaml_include_constructor)

    with open(...) as f:
        yml = yaml.load(f, loader)
```

`# noinspection PyTypeChecker` is there to prevent PEP-check warning *Expected type 'ScalarNode', got 'Node' instead* when passing `node: yaml.Node` to `loader.construct_scalar()`.

This solution fails if `yaml.load` input stream is not file stream, as `loader.name` does not contain the path in that case:

```py
class Reader(object):
    ...
    def __init__(self, stream):
        ...
        if isinstance(stream, str):
            self.name = "<unicode string>"
            ...
        elif isinstance(stream, bytes):
            self.name = "<byte string>"
            ...
        else:
            self.name = getattr(stream, 'name', "<file>")
            ...
```

In my use case, I know that only YAML files will be included, so the solution can be simplified further:

```py
def yaml_include_constructor(loader: yaml.Loader, node: yaml.Node) -> Any:
    """Include YAML file referenced with !include node"""
    with open(Path(loader.name).parent.joinpath(loader.construct_yaml_str(node)).resolve(), 'r') as f:
        return yaml.load(f, type(loader))


Loader = yaml.SafeLoader  # Works with any loader
Loader.add_constructor("!include", yaml_include_constructor)


def main():
    with open(...) as f:
        yml = yaml.load(f, Loader=Loader)
```

or even one-liner using lambda:

```py
Loader = yaml.SafeLoader  # Works with any loader
Loader.add_constructor("!include",
                       lambda l, n: yaml.load(Path(l.name).parent.joinpath(l.construct_scalar(n)).read_text(), type(l)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could inspire you, try to align to jbb conventions:

https://docs.openstack.org/infra/jenkins-job-builder/definition.html#inclusion-tags

`- job:
    name: test-job-include-raw-1
    builders:
      - shell:
          !include-raw: include-raw001-hello-world.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Adding on @Joshbode's initial answer above , I modified the snippet a little to support UNIX style wild card patterns.

I haven't tested in windows though.  I was facing an issue of splitting an array in a large yaml across multiple files for easy maintenance and was looking for a solution to refer multiple files within a same array of the base yaml. Hence the below solution. The solution does not support recursive reference. It only supports wildcards in a given directory level referenced in the base yaml.

```py
import yaml
import os
import glob


# Base code taken from below link :-
# Ref:https://stackoverflow.com/a/9577670
class Loader(yaml.SafeLoader):

    def __init__(self, stream):

        self._root = os.path.split(stream.name)[0]

        super(Loader, self).__init__(stream)

    def include(self, node):
        consolidated_result = None
        filename = os.path.join(self._root, self.construct_scalar(node))

        # Below section is modified for supporting UNIX wildcard patterns
        filenames = glob.glob(filename)
        
        # Just to ensure the order of files considered are predictable 
        # and easy to debug in case of errors.
        filenames.sort()
        for file in filenames:
            with open(file, 'r') as f:
                result = yaml.load(f, Loader)

            if isinstance(result, list):
                if not isinstance(consolidated_result, list):
                    consolidated_result = []
                consolidated_result += result
            elif isinstance(result, dict):
                if not isinstance(consolidated_result, dict):
                    consolidated_result = {}
                consolidated_result.update(result)
            else:
                consolidated_result = result

        return consolidated_result


Loader.add_constructor('!include', Loader.include)
```

**Usage**

```yaml
a:
  !include a.yaml

b:
  # All yamls included within b folder level will be consolidated
  !include b/*.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on previous posts:

```py
  class SimYamlLoader(yaml.SafeLoader):
        '''
        Simple custom yaml loader that supports include, e.g:

        main.yaml:

        - !include file1.yaml
        - !include dir/file2.yaml

        '''

        def __init__(self, stream):
            self.root = os.path.split(stream.name)[0]
            super().__init__(stream)

    def _include(loader, node):
        filename = os.path.join(loader.root, loader.construct_scalar(node))
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            return yaml.load(f, SimYamlLoader)
    SimYamlLoader.add_constructor('!include', _include)

    # example:
    with open('main.yaml', 'r') as f:
        lists = yaml.load(f, SimYamlLoader)
        # if you want to merge the lists
        data = functools.reduce(
            lambda x, y: x if y is None else {**x, **dict(y)}, lists, {})
        # python 3.10+:lambda x, y: x if y is None else x | dict(y), lists, {})
```

Answer (score -9):

Probably it was not supported when question was asked but you can import other YAML file into one:

```
imports: [/your_location_to_yaml_file/Util.area.yaml]
```

Though I don't have any online reference but this works for me.

Comment: This doesn't do any including at all. It creates a mapping with a sequence consisting of a single string "/your_location_to_yaml_file/Util.area.yaml", as value for the key `imports`.