# How to include a YAML file inside a YAML file in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

Is there a custom tag in YAML for ruby to include a YAML file inside a YAML file?

```
#E.g.:  
--- !include
filename: another.yml
```

A [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528281/how-can-i-include-an-yaml-file-inside-another) question was asked some time ago and there was no relevant answer.

I am wondering if there is some custom tag for Ruby similar to [this](http://docs.repoze.org/configuration/directives.html) one for Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I include an YAML file inside another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528281/how-can-i-include-an-yaml-file-inside-another)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found a way to address my scenario using ERB.

I monkey patched YAML module to add two new methods

```
module YAML
    def YAML.include file_name
      require 'erb'
      ERB.new(IO.read(file_name)).result
    end

    def YAML.load_erb file_name
      YAML::load(YAML::include(file_name))
    end  
end
```

I have three YAML files.

**mod1_config.yml**

```
mod1:
    age: 30
    city: San Francisco
```

**mod2_config.yml**

```
mod2:
    menu: menu1
    window: window1
```

**all_config.yml**

```
<%= YAML::include("mod1_config.yml") %>
<%= YAML::include("mod2_config.yml") %>
```

Parse the yaml file using the method `YAML::load_erb` instead of the method `YAML::load`.

```
  config = YAML::load_erb('all_config.yml') 
  config['mod1']['age'] # 30
  config['mod2']['menu'] # menu1
```

**Caveats:**

1. Does not support document merge
2. Last include overwrites same named keys

Comment: I get error `private method 'include' called for Psych:Module (NoMethodError)` any guesses how can I fix it ?
I have added the YAML module in `initializers/yaml.rb`

Comment: bravo @Harish it even works well with <<: *foo

Answer (score 19):

If you are in Rails, YAML can include ERB.

Combine that together, and here is how you can use `<%= %>` to include one file from another:

**database.yml**

```
<% if File.exists?('/tmp/mysql.sock') %>
<%= IO.read('config/database.mysql.yml') %>
<% else %>
<%= IO.read('config/database.sqlite.yml') %>
<% end %>
```

**database.sqlite.yml**

```
sqlite: &defaults
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *defaults
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *defaults
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *defaults
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

**database.mysql.yml**

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  # ... the rest of your mysql configuration ...
```

Answer (score 9):

If your aim is avoiding duplication in your YAML file, not necessarily including external file, I recommend doing something like this:

```
development: &default
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: db_dev
  pool: 5
  username: usr
  password: psw
  host: localhost
  port: 3306

dev_cache:
  <<: *default

new:
  <<: *default
  database: db_new

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db_test
```

Comment: You may need `YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'` for this to work http://stackoverflow.com/a/6140900/414220

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to inherit from another YAML file, there is a gem providing this functionality you are asking for by extending the ruby YAML library:

https://github.com/entwanderer/yaml_extend

https://rubygems.org/gems/yaml_extend

## Usage

yaml_extend adds the method YAML#ext_load_file to YAML.

This method works like the original YAML#load_file, by extending it with file inheritance.

### Examples

```
# start.yml
extends: 'super.yml'
data:
    name: 'Mr. Superman'
    age: 134    
    favorites:
        - 'Raspberrys'
```

-

```
# super.yml
data:
    name: 'Unknown'
    power: 2000
    favorites:
        - 'Bananas'
        - 'Apples'
```

#### Basic Inheritance

```
YAML.ext_load_file('start.yml')
```

results in

```
data:
    name: 'Mr. Superman'
    age: 134
    power: 2000
    favorites:
        - 'Bananas'
        - 'Apples'
        - 'Raspberrys'
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this:

**load_config.rb** (initializer)

```
cf_1 = YAML::load(File.read("/etc/my_app/config.yml"))
cf_2 = YAML::load(File.read(File.join(Rails.root, "config", "config.yml")))
CONFIG = cf_1.merge(cf_2)
```

Later, you can access config values by doing:

```
CONFIG['value']
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `!include` is not a directive but a tag.
2. it is not a feature of Python (or PyYAML) but a feature of the "poze" library:

   poze.configuration exposes a default directive named include.
3. YAML specification does not define such a standard tag.

Comment: YAML spec doesn't have the tag `!include`. I was hoping that somebody has written a custom tag similar to the custom tag in "poze" library. I guess its time to write the custom tag myself :-)

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you need it for. If you need to transport file, you can base64 encode internal yaml file.