# Ruby 1.9.2 patchlevel 180 - libyaml breaks yaml node reference

Tags: ruby, yaml

I used rvm upgrading to 1.9.2-p180. during the installation, libyaml 0.1.3 was fetched and installed.

Now when I have my database.yml in a rails project like this:

```
defaults: &defaults
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: UTF-8
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
  engine: InnoDB

test:
  <<: *defaults
  database: my_app_test
```

in console,

```
YAML.load_file("config/database.yml")
```

The result is:

```
{"test" => {"apapter" => "mysql"...}}
```

The problem is the "database" key is missing. it seems not to merge the defaults node and test node togther, rather it just copy the default node.

any idea?

Comment: You've probably got the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140493/database-yml-references-not-working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyway, upgrade to ruby-p290 solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I can't duplicate that, also using 1.9.2.180:

```
irb(main):002:0> YAML::load_file('./test.yml')
=> {"defaults"=>{"adapter"=>"mysql", "encoding"=>"UTF-8", "username"=>"root", "password"=>nil, "host"=>"localhost", "engine"=>"InnoDB"}, "test"=>{"adapter"=>"mysql", "encoding"=>"UTF-8", "username"=>"root", "password"=>nil, "host"=>"localhost", "engine"=>"InnoDB", "database"=>"my_app_test"}}
```

(Scroll right to see: `"database"=>"my_app_test"}}` )

Not sure if this is an answer as such, but I couldn't put the code in a comment.  If I have the wrong end of the stick I'll edit or delete...

Comment: Don't know why it works for you, man. Maybe you used syck. This is a known problem in p180