# Can a YML file access another YML file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, yaml

We have a site wide `config.yml` file which contacts api keys etc...

Can another one of my YML files access a value in the `config.yml`?

config.yml:

```
development:
    thing: 123123123123
```

plugin_config.yml:

```
development:
    thing: config.yml.development.thing
```

is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include a YAML file inside a YAML file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278241/how-to-include-a-yaml-file-inside-a-yaml-file)

Answer (score 7):

You can always parse it with ERB:

```
development:
    thing: 123123123123

development:
    thing: <%= YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read(Rails.root.join('config','config.yml'))).result)['development'] %>
```

Then load the first one and also parse it with ERB (in an initializer or something):

```
CONFIG = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read(Rails.root.join('config','plugin_config.yml'))).result)
```