# Is it possible to have multiple fixture files per model in rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing

In Rails 3.2, is it possible to have multiple fixture files for a given ActiveRecord object?

The client is requiring the test data be written in fixtures but also wants them to be manageable. I'd like to split up the fixtures a bit by introducing a 2nd set that the originals would include/require/render whatever.

I haven't been able to find anything via Google on how to do it and fixtures are not my cup of tea. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems to me like what you want to do is include a YAML file from another YAML file. Here's a question which covers how to do that: [How to include a YAML file inside a YAML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278241/how-to-include-a-yaml-file-inside-a-yaml-file)

Since fixtures already have ERB, it should be as simple as:

```
<%= IO.read(Rails.root.join "test/other_fixtures/fixture_to_load.yml") %>
```

Just make sure that the fixtures are outside of the primary fixture directory or the mechanism for loading fixtures will also attempt to map them to a model.

If you need ERB inside of the fixture, wrap it in `ERB.new`, such as:

```
<%= ERB.new(IO.read(Rails.root.join "test/other_fixtures/fixture_to_load.yml")).result %>
```

Comment: Ah. Thanks. This actually led me to a really simple solution. Since fixtures already have ERB, it as just this: <%= IO.read(Rails.root.join "test/other_fixtures/fixture_to_load.yml") %>

Comment: You're absolutely right - I didn't realize it would be this straight forward!