# Rails: Fixtures for same model from multiple files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, testing, activerecord, fixtures

I'm trying to populate a development database with fixtures for testing purposes.

I am populating a model's data using multiple fixture files in different directories. However, it seems like my fixture loading is not additive. That is, my table gets re-initialized from scratch every time.

This is my code loop:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('db', 'seeds', 'dev', '**/*.yml')].each do |file|
  puts "Loading #{file}"
  ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.create_fixtures(File.dirname(file), File.basename(file, '.yml'))
end
```

For example, my model `Article` has many fixture files that will write to it. i.e. `news.yml`, `tech.yml`, `recipies.yml`... etc.

Every one of those fixture files I have:

```
_fixture:
  model_class: Article

...rest of fixtures...
```

In the beginning of the file.

When I run my task, only the last `Article` fixture data gets retained.

How can I utilize all of the `Article` fixtures to initialize the model? (all of `news.yml`, `tech.yml`, `recipies.yml`)

Answer (score 0):

You could try sourcing the fixtures directly from the official fixtures file:

```
<%= IO.read(Rails.root.join "test/other_fixtures/fixture_to_load.yml") %>
```

In this case, a file like articles.yml might just become a shell file with `IO.read` statements to decompose into multiple files.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13036641/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-fixture-files-per-model-in-rails-3-2)