# YAML: add link / reference to external document

Tags: yaml

How can I add a link to a `YAML` file that points to, e.g. another web site? The description field would be fine.

I read the `YAML` documentation but could not find a reference to "external references".

Comment: What's the code you have a the moment?

Comment: I just added an html referece like <a href="../folder/file.html>here</a>. Page says, it cannot be parsed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Easy solution: descriptions use format Markdown, which allows links with the format

```
[I'm an inline-style link](https://www.google.com)
```

Comment: Tried this as a value for property of an action in GitHub Actions workflow.
Returns "can not read an implicit mapping pair; a colon is missing".

Comment: For my yaml parameter I had to put everything in quotation marks:
`"[I'm an inline-style link](https://www.google.com)"`

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same, this may help too.

```
 <a href="https://..." target="_blank">click to open the extarnal tab</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

YAML does not include any kind of "import" or "include" statement.
**BUT** what you can do is to use PyYAML (documentation [here](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#YAMLsyntax)). 
Also, read this previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528281/how-can-i-include-an-yaml-file-inside-another), there are some solutions you may want to use to your case.

Comment: I would be fine to have a clickable link to another file. No need to import one

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
title: Test Release and Updates
name: Developed and maintained by Testing Team
description: <a href="http://testing.test123.org/xx3/landing.gsp">Testing Landing Page</a>
theme: jekyll-theme-cayman
github:
  is_project_page: false
```

Comment: The link to the website is broken