# Gitlab CI: Passing dynamic variables

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am looking to pass varibales value dynamically as shown below to terraform image as mentioned in the  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41723062/concat-variable-names-in-gitlab)

```
image:
  name: hashicorp/terraform:light
  entrypoint:
    - /usr/bin/env
    - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
    - 'ACCESS_KEY_ID=${ENV}_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'
    - 'SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${ENV}_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
    - 'DEFAULT_REGION=${ENV}_AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'        
    - 'export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${!ACCESS_KEY_ID}'
    - 'export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${!SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}'
    - 'export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=${!DEFAULT_REGION}'
```

However, I am getting empty values. How can I pass dynamic values to the variables.

Comment: Let's assume ENV=DEV. Where do you set the variables E.g ENV, DEV_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion arises from the subtle fact, that the gitlab runner executes the commands passed into the script section using `sh` rather than `bash`

And the core issue is encountered that the following syntax

```
'export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${!ACCESS_KEY_ID}'
```

is understood correctly `only by bash` and `not by  sh`

Therefore, we need to workaround it by using syntax that is understood by sh

For your case, something like the following should do it

```
image:
  name: hashicorp/terraform:light
  entrypoint:
    - /usr/bin/env
    - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'


job:
  before_script:
   - ACCESS_KEY_ID=${ENV}_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
   - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(eval echo \$$ACCESS_KEY_ID )
   - SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${ENV}_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
   - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$( eval echo \$$SECRET_ACCESS_KEY )       
   - DEFAULT_REGION=${ENV}_AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
   - export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=$( eval echo \$$DEFAULT_REGION )
  script:
   - echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
   - echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
   - echo $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
```

Comment: I have tried but it didnt work. Also getting bad substitution if I tried in before_script as 

before_script:
- DEFAULT_REGION=${ENV}_AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
- export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=${!DEFAULT_REGION}

Comment: @gmairi please check again