# Resolve "$ref" in a YAML-File in Java

Tags: java, reference, yaml, swagger

I have a file with the "$ref" and want that it will be resolved
with the format for example:

```
spec:
 spaceDevelopers:
 $ref: '../someThing.yml'
```

I would like to resolve the `$ref: '../spaceDevelopers.yml'`

Inside the file in Java. 
I have searched for a library, but could not find a good example, how to do it.

My resources are: 
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/ 
And 
https://github.com/kalaspuffar/swagger-reader/blob/master/src/main/java/org/ea/swagger/NewReader.java

I would appreciate if someone could give me a code snippet, because I can not imagine, how to do it.

Thank you

Comment: It is rather unclear what you want to do. Do you want to reproduce swagger's `$ref` (i.e. create a YAML file with the `$ref` resolved)? Do you somehow want to replace `someThing.yml` with `spaceDevelopers.yml`? Please describe your expected output more clearly.

Comment: Adjusted, I want to reproduce swaggers ref, create a yml, even better it would be to adjust the current file and put the content inside it

Comment: Check out Swagger Parser's RefUtils for an example: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser/blob/master/modules/swagger-parser-v3/src/main/java/io/swagger/v3/parser/util/RefUtils.java

Comment: Also see [How can I include a YAML file inside another?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/528281/113116) for other ideas of how to implement includes in YAML.

Comment: The code you're using seems to [quietly ignore non-local references](https://github.com/kalaspuffar/swagger-reader/blob/master/src/main/java/org/ea/swagger/Reader.java#L77).

Comment: @flyx what do you mean?

Comment: @Schaumkuesschen This is a sister file to the code file you linked. I looked around to find the part of the code that actually handles `$ref` keys and that seemed to be it. However, I don't really know the relation between Reader and NewReader though.

Comment: Yes, 
I gave up on it. 
OpenAPI would be a way to handle it, but I could not find any code examples, which would match my requirements. 
That it replace the ref with the file content.

Comment: @Schaumkuesschen have you find the solution?