# Is there a way we can import a file into YAML in GCP Deployment Manager

Tags: google-deployment-manager

I am trying to create a configuration file in GCP Deployment Manager and i have a metadata file which needs to imported as text.

I know on how do it in .py file, but wondering on how to do it in YAML.

I tried different but none seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Deployment Manager can use the `imports` statement to import Jinja2 or Python templates into the root configuration file, plain YAML cannot be imported. This is limitation of YAML. It does not have "import" or "include" functionality.

A similar question has been discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15437697/11602913.

In a pure YAML deployment file, metadata can be provided literally, as described in the document

[Google Cloud Platform for AWS Professionals: Infrastructure Deployment Tools](https://cloud.google.com/docs/compare/aws/deployment-tools#metadata_helper_scripts_and_startup_scripts):

```
resources:
- name: my-first-vm-template
  type: compute.v1.instance
  properties:
   ...
   metadata:
     items:
     - key: startup-script
       value: "STARTUP-SCRIPT-CONTENTS"
```

If metadata should be loaded from a file, you have to use Jinja2 templates. There is an example at [codelabs.developers.google.com](https://codelabs.developers.google.com):

[Deploy Your Infrastructure Using Deployment Manager > Creating your deployment configuration](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/gcp-aws-deployment-manager/index.html?index=..%2F..index#2)

```
imports:
- path: instance.jinja
- path: ../startup-script.sh
  name: startup-script.sh
resources:
- name: my-instance
  type: instance.jinja
  properties:
    metadata-from-file:
      startup-script: startup-script.sh
```