# How to extend go-yaml to support custom tags

Tags: go, yaml

I have spent some time reading the code and docs of [go-yaml](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml/), but I have not found any way to do this, except forking the project..

I want to extend the YAML unmarshaller so that it can accept a custom YAML tag (`!include <file>` in this case), which in turn would allow me to add support for including files. This is easily implemented with other YAML libraries, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9577670/437174).

Is there any way to accomplish this, using the public interface of the library (or another yaml library)?

Comment: I forgot to note that somebody modified go-yaml to provide exactly this functionality, but it is on a forked and unused repo: https://github.com/sanathkr/go-yaml/commit/ed9d249f429b3f5a69f80a7abef6bfce81fef894

Comment: `go-yaml` does not support this, that's why you can't find it in the public API. You would have to fork it.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this is possible (since `v3`). You can load the whole YAML file into a `yaml.Node` and then walk over the structure. The trick is that `yaml.Node` is an intermediate representation which you can only access if you define an unmarshaler.
For example:

```golang
package main

import (
  "errors"
  "fmt"
  "io/ioutil"
  "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

// used for loading included files
type Fragment struct {
  content *yaml.Node
}

func (f *Fragment) UnmarshalYAML(value *yaml.Node) error {
  var err error
  // process includes in fragments
  f.content, err = resolveIncludes(value)
  return err
}

type IncludeProcessor struct {
  target interface{}
}

func (i *IncludeProcessor) UnmarshalYAML(value *yaml.Node) error {
  resolved, err := resolveIncludes(value)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  return resolved.Decode(i.target)
}

func resolveIncludes(node *yaml.Node) (*yaml.Node, error) {
  if node.Tag == "!include" {
    if node.Kind != yaml.ScalarNode {
      return nil, errors.New("!include on a non-scalar node")
    }
    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(node.Value)
    if err != nil {
      return nil, err
    }
    var f Fragment
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(file, &f)
    return f.content, err
  }
  if node.Kind == yaml.SequenceNode || node.Kind == yaml.MappingNode {
    var err error
    for i := range node.Content {
      node.Content[i], err = resolveIncludes(node.Content[i])
      if err != nil {
        return nil, err
      }
    }
  }
  return node, nil
}

type MyStructure struct {
  // this structure holds the values you want to load after processing
  // includes, e.g.
  Num int
}

func main() {
  var s MyStructure
  yaml.Unmarshal([]byte("!include foo.yaml"), &IncludeProcessor{&s})
  fmt.Printf("Num: %v", s.Num)
}
```

Code prints `Num: 42` when a file `foo.yaml` exists with the content `num: 42`.

Answer (score 1):

Modified @flyx's original code a little to make it modular for adding custom resolvers.

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

var tagResolvers = make(map[string]func(*yaml.Node) (*yaml.Node, error))

type Fragment struct {
    content *yaml.Node
}

func (f *Fragment) UnmarshalYAML(value *yaml.Node) error {
    var err error
    // process includes in fragments
    f.content, err = resolveTags(value)
    return err
}

type CustomTagProcessor struct {
    target interface{}
}

func (i *CustomTagProcessor) UnmarshalYAML(value *yaml.Node) error {
    resolved, err := resolveTags(value)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return resolved.Decode(i.target)
}

func resolveTags(node *yaml.Node) (*yaml.Node, error) {
    for tag, fn := range tagResolvers {
        if node.Tag == tag {
            return fn(node)
        }
    }
    if node.Kind == yaml.SequenceNode || node.Kind == yaml.MappingNode {
        var err error
        for i := range node.Content {
            node.Content[i], err = resolveTags(node.Content[i])
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
        }
    }
    return node, nil
}

func resolveIncludes(node *yaml.Node) (*yaml.Node, error) {
    if node.Kind != yaml.ScalarNode {
        return nil, errors.New("!include on a non-scalar node")
    }
    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(node.Value)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    var f Fragment
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(file, &f)
    return f.content, err
}

func resolveGetValueFromEnv(node *yaml.Node) (*yaml.Node, error) {
    if node.Kind != yaml.ScalarNode {
        return nil, errors.New("!getValueFromEnv on a non-scalar node")
    }
    value := os.Getenv(node.Value)
    if value == "" {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("environment variable %v not set", node.Value)
    }
    var f Fragment
    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(value), &f)
    return f.content, err
}

func AddResolvers(tag string, fn func(*yaml.Node) (*yaml.Node, error)) {
    tagResolvers[tag] = fn
}

func main() {

    // Register custom tag resolvers
    AddResolvers("!include", resolveIncludes)
    AddResolvers("!getValueFromEnv", resolveGetValueFromEnv)

    type MyStructure struct {
        // this structure holds the values you want to load after processing
        // includes, e.g.
        Num int
    }
    var s MyStructure
    os.Setenv("FOO", `{"num": 42}`)
    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte("!getValueFromEnv FOO"), &CustomTagProcessor{&s})
    if err != nil {
        panic("Error encountered during unmarshalling")
    }

    fmt.Printf("\nNum: %v", s.Num)

    err = yaml.Unmarshal([]byte("!include foo.yaml"), &CustomTagProcessor{&s})
    if err != nil {
        panic("Error encountered during unmarshalling")
    }
    fmt.Printf("\nNum: %v", s.Num)
}
```