# How can I include a specific data from YAML file inside another?

Tags: python, yaml

I have a very similar structure and scenario to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528281/how-can-i-include-a-yaml-file-inside-another) and it help me a lot, but I'm looking for a more specific situation, I wanna include to my yaml file just a data from another yaml file, not the complete file. Something like:

**UPDATED**: I correct the structure of files below to describe properly my scenario, sorry.

foo.yaml

```
a: 1
b:
    - 1.43
    - 543.55
    - item : !include {I wanna just the [1, 2, 3] from} bar.yaml
```

bar.yaml

```
- 3.6
- [1, 2, 3]
```

Right now, I'm importing all the second file, but I don't need all and don't figure it out the proper solution since yesterday. Below is my actual structure:

foo.yaml

```
variables: !include bar.yaml #I'm importing the entire file for now and have to navegate in that to get what I need.
a: 1
b:
    - 1.43
    - 543.55
```

Comment: YAML is not a programming language, and `!include` is not a standard tag. You can program something yourself with a custom constructor: https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll look if the link can give me the correct way to solve that, and then awnser you =D

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have looked this documentation before, and tried to use the sugested way (yaml_load.SafeLoader), but does not work properly to my code. I'll read again, maybe now it makes a little more sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own custom include constructor:

```
bar_yaml = """
- 3.6
- [1, 2, 3]
"""

foo_yaml = """
variables: !include [bar.yaml, 1]
a: 1
b:
    - 1.43
    - 543.55
"""

def include_constructor(loader, node):
  selector = loader.construct_sequence(node)
  name = selector.pop(0)
  # in actual code, load the file named by name.
  # for this example, we'll ignore the name and load the predefined string
  content = yaml.safe_load(bar_yaml)
  # walk over the selector items and descend into the loaded structure each time.
  for item in selector:
    content = content[item]
  return content

yaml.add_constructor('!include', include_constructor, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)

print(yaml.safe_load(foo_yaml))
```

This `!include` will treat the first item in the given sequence as file name and the following items as sequence indexes (or dictionary keys). E.g. you can do `!include [bar.yaml, 1, 2]` to only load the `3`.

Comment: Hi flyx, thanks for the tip. Actually I use something really similar, but I see my question was not properly clear, so I updated. I wanna know if is possible to get the just part of data from a child yaml in a subitem on the main yaml. Have you seem or tried somethink like that? I don't see any examples in the searchs I'm doing.

Comment: How does writing `!include [bar.yaml, 1]` using the code I posted not solve your updated question?