# How can one override the values of a yaml file with the values of another yaml file?

Tags: python, yaml

I have 2 yaml files one has the default values of some settings and anther has null values and will be overridden when there are some changes. There is a set to default button that should set the settings to their default values. I want the yaml file of the customized settings to be overriden by the values of the defaultyaml file

I tried with dump and write but didn't quite work.

Comment: You decode the YAML files, manipulate the resulting data structures in some way, and write a new data structure out to a YAML file. Your question is entirely about the middle step, independent of YAML itself.

Comment: You could use an [`!include` constructor as of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9577670/20599896)

Comment: Try hydra / omegaconf packages