Large YAML document represented as file hierarchy
A program of mine has a large configuration file in YAML syntax. I am thinking about splitting the large file into multiple files to make them easier to edit (ideally files will be small, fitting one page). The loader procedure will traverse the file hierarchy, use file names as YAML associative array keys, and insert file contents as the corresponding values.  Only associative arrays at the top of YAML hierarchy will be split this way, any other syntax will have to be contained within leaf files.
A simple file hierarchy example demonstrated using GNU find and tail:
$ find . -type f
./foo
./bar
./baz/color
./baz/shape

$ tail `find . -type f`
==> ./foo <==
color: red
shape: circle

==> ./bar <==
color: [black, white]
shape: "deep channel"

==> ./baz/color <==
magenta

==> ./baz/shape <==
star

The YAML equivalent would be:
foo:
  color: red
  shape: circle
bar:
  color: [black, white]
  shape: "deep channel"
baz:
  color: magenta
  shape: star

The idea seems simple and practical but surprisingly I cannot find any implementations.  I am about to wrap my own but if you have seen something similar I would like to take a look before I have built another bicycle :)

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528281/how-can-i-include-a-yaml-file-inside-another since this would be your own custom implementation ... I suggest you build the bicycle, there is no standard for this bicycle at least.

@Ironluca thanks for the ref and encouragement. Indeed worth trying as most people suggest explicit include while I wanted it to work with minimum efforts: just add a file and the loader will pick it up.

As @Ironluca pointed out, related topic of including one YAML file into another has been discussed at stackoverflow. There is no standard YAML syntax for file inclusion, so people introduce custom conventions that explicitly point to a file to be inserted at specific point of a YAML file.
But I wanted automatic assembly of the large YAML file from all YAML snippets found under a directory. So I ended up with the following simple wrapper over Perl5 YAML.pm:
#!/usr/bin/perl

use YAML;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

sub splityaml_load {
    my ($file) = @_;
    if (-f $file) {
        return YAML::LoadFile($file);
    }
    elsif (-d $file) {
        my $ret = {};
        if (-f "$file/conf.yml") {
            $ret = splityaml_load("$file/conf.yml");
        }
        opendir (my $dh, $file) or die "$file: $!\n";
        local $_;
        while (readdir $dh) {
            if (/^\w+(-\d+)?$/) { # identifier or identifier-N
                if (exists $ret->{$_}) {
                    warn "$file/$_: also seen in $file/conf.yml\n";
                }
                my $z = splityaml_load("$file/$_");
                $ret->{$_} = $z;
            }
        }
        return $ret;
    }
    else {
        die "$file: $!\n";
    }
}

@ARGV or die "Usage: splityaml2json {FILE|DIR}\n";
my $x = splityaml_load($ARGV[0]);
#print Dumper($x);
print YAML::Dump($x);
#print encode_json($x);

exit 0;

The loader script requires that every file in the hierarchy contained valid YAML, so I changed the original example as follows:

$ find conf -type f
conf/conf.yml
conf/subsystem1/conf.yml
conf/subsystem2/conf.yml
conf/subsystem2/dimensions/conf.yml

$ tail `find conf -type f`
==> conf/conf.yml <==
common_parm1: val1

==> conf/subsystem1/conf.yml <==
color: green
shape: circle

==> conf/subsystem2/conf.yml <==
color: [black, white]
shape: box

==> conf/subsystem2/dimensions/conf.yml <==
- 10
- 20
- 30

Here is the "large" YAML merged from the snippets above:
$ splityaml2json.pl conf
---
common_parm1: val1
subsystem1:
  color: green
  shape: circle
subsystem2:
  color:
    - black
    - white
  dimensions:
    - 10
    - 20
    - 30
  shape: box

